# Can we have "Chroma key" technique using plain CSS or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This one is not trivial. I want to create a chroma key menu. For those not familiar, it is the same in video with the green background (or whatever color) being removed and special background is added.

[image]

I have images as a background in a menu. What I want is to set in someway the section where the background is transparent and the rest being filled with a color. In the example below, the background of the menu is image. Can we have such a background without one?

I am interested in unified solutions, not ones using css3.

Comment: If you can use JavaScript/jQuery, you really should have tagged your question as such.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to achieve, but couldn't you just use PNGs with alpha-transparency? That's how I would implement what you have posted above; but like I say, I'm not sure if I fully grok the requirements!

Comment: To add: I think it, if it's possible, it would be very difficult (and very slow) to do chroma keying and composite effects a la the video world.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm happy to be proven wrong, but I'm fairly sure the answer is no, not even with CSS3. *Maybe* using IE's very advanced `filter()`s but those aren't cross-browser.

Using a transparent channel for the background is the only way to go. It won't be trivial, but you could use a server-side script to change a specific colour into the transparent colour.

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) should be able to do this. [Here's](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/color_basics/#opaque) a promising example.

However, these examples are for replacing **one** colour. Whether it's possible to make this look good for anti-aliased edges (where the "transparent" colour blends into the surface colour, creating a mixture that the program would have to detect), I don't know.

If at *all* possible, use proper transparency from the start.

Comment: I am aware of image magic. Thank you very much for the response. In the near feature, I might implement a wordpress plugin that does the job. I hope somebody has done this already!

Answer (score 0):

I imagine this would be possible on the client-side by copying the image into a `<canvas>` rendering context, processing the image data (like ImageMagick does) then outputting a data uri  which you can use as the CSS background-image of your menu.

For reference see:

http://www.hmp.is.it/creating-chroma-key-effect-html5-canvas/

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-get-image-data-url/